# How to convert a specific PostgreSQL query to laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Im trying to convert a postgresql query to the laravel query builder style.
I have almost no experience with the laravel query builder. I dont want to use the DB raw.

```
SELECT ca1.component, ca1.previousfeeder, COUNT(ca1.previousfeeder)
FROM mydbcarrdata_10.carrier ca1
WHERE ca1.component IN (
                    SELECT e.articlename
                    FROM mydbcarrdata_10.carrier ca
                    JOIN mydbcompdata_10.component co
                    ON ca.component = co.name
                    JOIN mydbmanldata_10.entry e
                    ON e.articlename = co.name
                    JOIN mydbmanldata_10.header h
                    ON h.id = e.headerid
                    JOIN mydbmanldata_10.mandata m
                    ON h.layoutid = m.id
                    JOIN mydblytldata_10.layout l
                    ON m.layout = l.name
                    WHERE l.name = 'M2077F_bottom'
                    GROUP BY e.articlename
                    ) 
GROUP BY ca1.component, ca1.previousfeeder
ORDER BY ca1.component asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found the corresponding query using the query builder:

```
DB::table('mydbcarrdata_10.carrier')->select(DB::raw('component, previousfeeder, count(previousfeeder)'))
        ->whereIn('component', DB::table('mydbcarrdata_10.carrier')->select('articlename')
                                                        ->join('mydbcompdata_10.component', 'component.name', '=', 'carrier.component')
                                                        ->join('mydbmanldata_10.entry', 'component.name', '=', 'entry.articlename')
                                                        ->join('mydbmanldata_10.header', 'entry.headerid', '=', 'header.id')
                                                        ->join('mydbmanldata_10.mandata', 'mandata.id', '=', 'header.layoutid')
                                                        ->join('mydblytldata_10.layout', 'layout.name', '=', 'mandata.layout')
                                                        ->where('layout.name', '=', 'M2077F_bottom')
                                                        ->groupBy('entry.articlename')
                                                        ->pluck('articlename')
                                                    )
        ->groupBy('component', 'previousfeeder')
        ->orderBy('component', 'asc')
        ->get();
```